# Can you use peacemaker with keepalived as communication layer?

Tags: linux, high-availability, failovercluster, drbd, keepalived

I'm new to HA topic and I'm trying to get some bigger picture here. I have 2 hosts that run few services - mostly `nginx` and `NFS` for other servers. My primary goal was to make `nginx` redundant. As I knew VRRP from networking equipment I decided to use `keepalived`. Unfortunately to my surprise it turned out that NFS HA is not as simple as changing ip.

Most of tutorials around the web describe `DRBD+peacemaker+(heartbeat/corosync)` combo and it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I've read about role of each of those components and came to conclusion that `keepalived` does pretty much the same as `heartbeat/peacemaker`.

So my question is - can `peacemaker` use `keepalived` as communication layer instead of those popular two solutions or it's not compatible? I must say I'm really satisfied with rapid switch time provided by `keepalived`.

Comment: 1st: it's `pacemaker` not `peacemaker` :), 2nd: keepalived and pacemaker are somewhat comparable, but not the same. Pacemaker+corosync/heartbeat+DRBD (_usually_) are for active/standby HA solutions, whereas keepalived (also _usually_) is used for "active/active", e. g. nginx load balancers. tl;dr: keepalived is the "simpler" variant of pacemaker, but they are not necsessarily interchangeable.